# Can't create .txt files

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have it like this:

```
file=new File(pathString+"/TileRecordings/",jTextField1.getText()+".txt");
```

and then after null checking etc...

```
file.createNewFile();
```

Thing is, if the texfield value was 'test' it would create 'text.txt' AS A FOLDER. Not an actual text file.
Is this a Ubuntu only thing? How do I force it to literally create a text file, not a folder named 'test.txt'.

Comment: @cricket_007 It's in the format of (String parent , String child) so not sure why you're telling me I have a comma there, when it's supposed to be there. Also, this is a perfectly valid example. You literally don't need anything else to make this work. I did mention after null checking such as if(!file.exists) and then directory creations if they don't exist using file.mkdirs(). Not sure how either are relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try features from [java.nio.file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html)
for example:

```
Path temp = Paths.get(pathString+"/TileRecordings/"+jTextField1.getText()+".txt");
Files.write(temp, contentToSave.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: Appears that my method also works, so does yours. Only figured out after I decided to remove the file.mkdirs() method I had when checking if the path to it exists. Guess it also made the final string as a directory path, weird. I simply removed it and it creates .txt files as intended. going to mark you as correct, since it certainly isn't wrong ;)

Comment: @xmaxert So the whole error was caused by a line of code *that you didn't include in the question*? That's why you should always provide a [mcve]!